# make div bigger and animate bigger section upwards on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to animate a div upwards when a user hovers on the div.

I am able to animate the div making it bigger, however the animation happens downwards. I am trying to keep the bottom of the div remain in the same place, and have a smooth animating increasing the size of the div upwards.

[See jsfiddle here which](https://jsfiddle.net/x3cL1cpt/) demonstrates what my code is currently doing.

Please see code below:

```css
.box {
  height: 170px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  width: 50%;
}

.content {
  background-color: #e3e4e6;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.content:hover {
  height: 110%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">TEST</div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you increase the height is gonna increase towards bottom.

Comment: @Piyush.kapoor so how to i switch this behavior

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/pkapoor1989/utqdpfcz/1/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this using `transform:scaleY()` and set the `transform-origin` to `bottom`. I also put a margin-top:100px to see the effect better. Also you can use `transition` to make the scale smoother

You also need to scale back the text.

See here: **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3vm44Ljm/3/)**

You need to scale the text back to it's original state in the same time that you scale the div. so if you scale the div 2 times. You need to scale back the text with 1/2 , same if you scale 3 times...scale back with 1/3

In this case you enlarge `.content` by `1.5` so you need to scale down the text inside by 1/1.5 = 0.66

Code:

```css
.box {
  height: 170px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  width: 50%;
}

.content {
  background-color: #e3e4e6;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 300px;
  transition:0.3s;
}

.content:hover p {
  transform: scaleY(0.66);
  transform-origin: top;
}

.content:hover {
  transform: scaleY(1.5);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">
    <p>
      TEST
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this (I have no other idea...): You can give to the class "box" a bigger height (I put a red border around, so you can see it) than the class "content". After that, you can use flexbox, to put the class "content" on the bottom. After that, you can do it with hover to change your heigth upwards and fill it. With transition you can make a nice animation. I hope this is good enough. Perhaps there is also a way with jQUery at the moment I havn't got an idea. Let me know, if this helps you (I'm not sure if I understanded the question well) - Cheers. (Important: This heights and so on are just random values for testing)

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.content {
  background-color: #e3e4e6;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: height 1s;
  /* Safari */
  transition: height 1s;
}
.content:hover {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">TEST</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use css, just use:

```
.content:hover {
  margin-top: -50px;
  height: 110%;
}
```

See [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x3cL1cpt/3/)

Comment: i want the bottom of the div to remain in the same place.

Comment: Just modify the height = to margin top https://jsfiddle.net/x3cL1cpt/8/

Answer (score 0):

since there isn't any space at top to expand, you may give an extra margin initially and remove it on hover like this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ManojSalvi/0dffxmzz/) -

```
.box {
  height: 170px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  width: 50%;

}

.content {
    background-color: #e3e4e6;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:25px;
}

.content:hover {
  height: 110%;
  margin-top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me for some reason, when I tried to use transform and scale, it did not work. But what I did was I changed the font-size instead and it worked!

Something like this should work

```css
div:hover {
   font-size: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Set `top` property with the value of `height - 100 * -1`

https://jsfiddle.net/x3cL1cpt/7/

```
.content:hover {
  height: 110%;
  top: -10%;
  position: relative;
}
```

Why position relative? It's because I move the box, but without modifying the space that the box occuped. If you need to modify that space, change `top` with `margin-top`.

Answer (score -1):

Replace this CSS with your current, needed to add `transition`:

```
.box {
  height: 170px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  width: 50%;
}

.content {
    background-color: #e3e4e6;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 1s all ease;

}

.content:hover {
      transform: scaleY(1.2);
    transform-origin: bottom right;
}
```